# unexpected EOF while parsing : web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = input("enter your url here : " )
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href',none)
```

why i'm getting this error ?

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(tag.get('href',none)` needs to end with another `)`
liek this:

```
print(tag.get('href',none))
```

Comment: yeaa, thanks bruh. it turns out to be my negligence again :'(